# Не выполняется запрос при созданном подключении к БД

Tags: c++, qt, sql-server

Всем привет, возникла проблема
Подключаюсь к БД, соединение устанавливается, но когда выполняю запрос, выдает ошибку: QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
В чем может быть проблема?

Файл .cpp:

```
#include "firstform.h"
#include "ui_firstform.h"

FirstForm::FirstForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FirstForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-D1ATSIQ;DATABASE=Test;");
    db.setUserName("admin");
    db.setPassword("111111");

    if (!db.open())
    {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage(QSqlError(db.lastError()).text());
    }
    else
    {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Соединение успешно установлено!!!");
    }

    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
}

FirstForm::~FirstForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void FirstForm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if (!query.exec("SELECT Name FROM People WHERE Age > 18"))
    {
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

.h:

```
#ifndef FIRSTFORM_H
#define FIRSTFORM_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
class FirstForm;
}

class FirstForm : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FirstForm(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~FirstForm();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::FirstForm *ui;

    QSqlDatabase db;

    QSqlQuery query;
};

#endif // FIRSTFORM_H
```

Answer (score 2):

У Вас `QSqlQuery` никак не связан с созданной базой данных, попробуйте такой вариант:

```
void FirstForm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSqlQuery q(db);
    if (!q.exec("SELECT Name FROM People WHERE Age > 18"))
    {
        qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

Судя по документации, если не указывать явно, какую `QSqlDatabase` использовать `QSqlQuery`. то используется дефолтная база данных. Но я не уверен, что созданная Вами база сама устанавливается как дефолтная.

Дополнено: 
Для того чтоб оставить `QSqlQuery` как член класса, скорее всего будет работать такая схема:

```
FirstForm::FirstForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FirstForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-D1ATSIQ;DATABASE=Test;");
    db.setUserName("admin");
    db.setPassword("111111");

    if (!db.open())
    {
       ui->statusBar->showMessage(QSqlError(db.lastError()).text());
    }
    else
    {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Соединение успешно установлено!!!");
    }

    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();

    query = QSqlQuery(db);
}
```

Почему не работает Ваш вариант? потому что `QSqlQuery` создается еще до того как Вы проинициализировали `QSqlDatabase`, соответственно используется дефолтная (пустая) база данных.

Comment: Да, действительно, все заработало, спасибо.
Но вообще странно, вот пример из документации и тут такого нет...
QSqlQuery query("SELECT country FROM artist");
    while (query.next()) {
        QString country = query.value(0).toString();
        doSomething(country);
    }

Comment: @КириллРазуваев, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Нашел и исправил ошибку, надо делать вот так.
Единственное, не понятно вот что. Почему нельзя объявлять переменную query в .h?
.cpp:

```
#include "firstform.h"
#include "ui_firstform.h"

FirstForm::FirstForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FirstForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-D1ATSIQ;DATABASE=Test;");
    db.setUserName("admin");
    db.setPassword("111111");
    db.open();

    if (!db.open())
    {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage(QSqlError(db.lastError()).text());
    }
    else
    {
        ui->statusBar->showMessage("Соединение успешно установлено!!!");
    }

    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
}

FirstForm::~FirstForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void FirstForm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    if (!query.exec("SELECT Name FROM People WHERE Age > 18"))
    {
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

.h:

```
#ifndef FIRSTFORM_H
#define FIRSTFORM_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
class FirstForm;
}

class FirstForm : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FirstForm(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~FirstForm();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::FirstForm *ui;

    QSqlDatabase db;
};

#endif // FIRSTFORM_H
```